# allow the svg to take the full width

Tags: html, css, sass

after realizing the style on Figma then trying to convert to HTML/CSS I noticed that the svg does not take all the width as is indicated in the image especially the wave in black, I tried several techniques like scale transformation but that's not the goal I just want the wave to take all the width so that we can zoom the page quietly, I created a copy of the example here: https://codepen.io/HalasProject/pen/xxRxKaN

[image]

The Html Code of SVG:

```
<svg class="bg-svg" width="1360" height="402" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="Group 3">
    <rect id="rectangle" width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange" />
    <path id="Oval" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1000.89 378C1077.38 378 1139.39 315.991 1139.39 239.5C1139.39 163.009 1077.38 101 1000.89 101C924.4 101 862.392 163.009 862.392 239.5C862.392 315.991 924.4 378 1000.89 378Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.24" />
    <g id="points" class="animated pulse infinite" style="animation-duration: 6s;">
      <path id="Oval_2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1131.08 311.378C1144.72 311.378 1155.77 300.325 1155.77 286.689C1155.77 273.054 1144.72 262 1131.08 262C1117.45 262 1106.39 273.054 1106.39 286.689C1106.39 300.325 1117.45 311.378 1131.08 311.378Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.48" />
      <path id="Polygon" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M801.844 179L816.296 193.452L801.844 207.904L787.392 193.452L801.844 179Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.48" />
      <path id="Polygon_2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M972.009 35L1001.52 64.5065L972.009 94.013L942.503 64.5065L972.009 35Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.17" />
      <path id="Polygon_3" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M721.478 101.242L733.054 118.086L716.21 129.662L704.634 112.818L721.478 101.242Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.48" />
      <path id="Polygon_4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M807.869 37.6337L819.446 54.4776L802.602 66.054L791.025 49.2102L807.869 37.6337Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.48" />
      <path id="Polygon_5" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1099.07 72.937L1106.29 80.163L1099.07 87.3891L1091.84 80.163L1099.07 72.937Z" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.54" />
    </g>
    <path id="Vector" d="M0 370.278L37.7778 338.556C75.5556 306.834 151.111 243.389 226.667 238.135C302.222 232.485 377.778 286.016 453.333 280.365C528.889 275.112 604.444 211.667 680 206.413C755.556 200.763 831.111 254.294 906.667 290.973C982.222 327.651 1057.78 349.46 1133.33 338.556C1208.89 327.651 1284.44 286.016 1322.22 264.504L1360 243.389V402H1322.22C1284.44 402 1208.89 402 1133.33 402C1057.78 402 982.222 402 906.667 402C831.111 402 755.556 402 680 402C604.444 402 528.889 402 453.333 402C377.778 402 302.222 402 226.667 402C151.111 402 75.5556 402 37.7778 402H0V370.278Z" fill="#273036" />
    <rect id="airplane" x="762" y="168.012" width="407" height="204" transform="rotate(-13.5 762 168.012)" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image0" transform=" scale(0.00104423 0.00208333)" />
    </pattern>
    <image id="image0" xlink:href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/mG7vldemsGRDLaAD8Wu5GT7WxfSQprqChFjz5u-KXIIhX1y5UXB1dGARfGzU47XdUYr02jn09LcLxGHSBFaRzUTIqUrOuDMgyQf31SOTlXhLkZkBKf02KddK3My_bzk3" width="960" height="480" />
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wave in your SVG is smaller than the orange background. Easiest approach is to make them the same width in your design tool.

Comment: You considered the scenario when we zoom in or out the page !